# Woocommerce product variation extremely slow with custom price filter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a function which updates the price of a variation depending on a few conditions. Our shop sells courses and based on date (custom field), variations past todays date are removed from the dropdown selection.

Everything works as it should. However, the problem is, the product page is very slow and the filter adds 5-8 seconds to the load time.

When I put an echo in the function outputting the variation ID it outputs 12 times per the amount of variations. We have around 20 Variations so this functions runs 240+times.

Here is the filter and function:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'repeat_price_filter', 10, 2); 

function repeat_price_filter($price, $product_this){
    if(  isset($product_this->variation_id) ):

        $wc_pf = new WC_Product_Factory();
        $var_product = $wc_pf->get_product(  $product_this->variation_id );

        //if condtions, modify price here.

    endif;

    return $price;

}
```

How can I find out what's calling this filter repeatedly? I tried putting an IF in the to check for only instock variations which helped marginally.

I have another function which updates the price for the product page, is there any way to ONLY use this filter for the cart/checkout etc?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use your custom updating price function only in cart and checkout, why you dont use WooCommerce conditional tags in an **`if`** statement, this way: `if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ){ // Calculate price code }`

Comment: Thanks, that's a great suggestion. By using those conditions I was afraid I may miss the price update in other locations I may not be aware of. I ended up using if(!is_product()) so it works well for the time being. However, I'd still like to know what functions would be calling this filter so I can fine-tune this function further.